# Switch between tabs on iOS Safari using Appium

Tags: java, safari, appium, appium-ios

I am trying to run my Appium tests on real iOS device. However, I cannot figure how to switch between tabs on Safari. I open a page on Safari using Appium IOSDriver instance. I then click a link on the page that opens a new tab. Now I wish to close this tab or at least switch back to the original window.

I have tried the following solutions but none of them seem to help:

1. Perform touch action to open the tabs interface, did not manage to click the tabs option.

   ```
   TouchAction ta = new TouchAction(driver);
   int h=driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight();
   int w=driver.manage().window().getSize().getWidth();
   ta.tap(h-50,w-50).perform();
   ```
2. Tried switch back to original context, did not help

   ```
   for (String contextName : contextNames) {
       if(!contextName.equals(original)) {
           WebViewContext = contextName;
           ((AppiumDriver) driver).context(WebViewContext);
           Thread.sleep(4000);
           driver.close();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Tried Javascript, no success

   ```
   Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();
   String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
   ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open();");
   Set<String> newWindow = driver.getWindowHandles();
   newWindow.removeAll(windows);
   driver.switchTo().window(original);
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the below way and it works for me:

```
    IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver();
    driver.get("url to be opened");
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathOfElementToBeclicked"));

    ele.click(); //New window opens

    Set<String> contextView = ((AppiumDriver)driver).getContextHandles();
    ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>(contextView);        
    ((AppiumDriver)driver).context(s.get(contextView.size()-1));
    driver.close();
```

Give it a shot. Hope this helps

Comment: For some reason, the same script didnt work for me previously, notice code snippet (2) in my question. However, I tried it again after reading your answer with some waits/sleep and it seems to do the trick. Thanks